# Redirect users to the Play Store on the web version of my app if they're on mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a flutter application that uses the Android and Web build targets. When I'm visiting:

- the web version on an Android phone, I'd like to redirect the user to the Google Play Store
- the web version on a desktop, I'd like to show a button to go to the play store, to advertise the fact that an App exists
- on the Android version, do and show nothing.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To launch the URL, I used the url_launcher package.
To detect the web version, one can use kIsWeb exported by the foundation package. Note that the proposal often seen on the web, to check Platform is not working on Flutter Web (not implemented). Similarly, defaultTargetPlatform is TargetPlatform.android on Chrome Mobile, so that can't be used to detect the application version.

```dart
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Launch the app store URL if we're on web and on android
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android && kIsWeb) {
      launch(
          "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.id",
           webOnlyWindowName: '_self',
      );
    }

    [... return my normal web page design, the following is part of a Column() ... ]

                  !kIsWeb
                      ? []
                      : <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height:8),
                          Text("or, if you have an Android Mobile phone:"),
                          SizedBox(height: 8),
                          ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    launch(
                                        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.id");
                                  },
                              child: Text(
                                  "Open the App on the Google Play store!")
                          )
                      ],
```

EDIT: The "webOnlyWindowName: '_self'," when auto-redirecting will replace the current tab. Previously I did not have that and chrome mobile would consider this a pop-up, that users would dismiss most of the time. The last problem is this opens the web version of the play store, I'd like it to open the real play store...